# Compatible methods for View on Android 2.2 (setScale & setPivot)

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-view, android-3.0-honeycomb

I has an application that was designed for Honeycomb and now I need to make it run on the old Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2).

But I used some methods that are not part of the API on Froyo:

```
        //child is a View
        child.setPivotX(0);
        child.setPivotY(0);
        child.setScaleY(scaleFromOriginal);
        child.setScaleX(scaleFromOriginal);
```

Someone knows how achieve the same result on 2.2?

PS: I'm looking on Compatibility Package, but there's no helper for those methods.

Answer (score 7):

you can use Nineoldandroids

```
ViewHelper.setPivotY(child, 0f);
ViewHelper.setPivotX(child, 0f);

ViewHelper.setScaleY(child, scaleFromOriginal);
ViewHelper.setScaleX(child, scaleFromOriginal);
```

http://nineoldandroids.com/#usage

Comment: Nice, so that's its what's nineoldandroid is.. i'm going to test it